# JavaFX equivalent to java.awt.EventQueue

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2

Does JavaFX contain an equivalent to java.awt.EventQueue? For my application I need to intercept all GUI related events such as mouse and keyboard input, and so far I haven't been able to find a way to do it without attaching listeners to every GUI element.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't quite the same as the question in your title, but to intercept all events, you can add an EventFilter to the Scene:

```
scene.addEventFilter(Event.ANY, new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            System.out.println(event);
        }
});
```

If you need to veto the event, call `event.consume()`